# Svelte - Pop-up window calendar

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, svelte

I have a calendar made with Svelte, in which, when clicking on a day, a pop-up window opens in which you can see the events that take place on that day. The problem I have is that when I close it and click on another day with other events, the popup window opens with this new day, but the content of the popup window is the same as the previous one, that is, I see the events of the day I previously clicked. The only way to see the events of the day that I want to see in the pop-up window is by clicking on a day without events after the first one, and then I will be able to see the events of the next day.
How could I solve it?
Thank you.

```
<div id="activity-background" style="--display: block;" on:click={closePopup}></div>
```

And, in javascript part:

```
let doc=null;
function closePopup() {
    doc = null;
}
```

Comment: How is the window opened and the event information passed?